# How to convert 1280x720 .jpg files to 640x240 .ppm files using ImageMagick's `convert` command?

Tags: command-line, image-processing, imagemagick, format-conversion

I have some image files (width: 1280 px, height: 720 px, colored, `.jpg`) and I want to first reduce them to half both vertically and horizontally, i.e. to 640x360 px, and then I want to cut 120 rows (upper 60 rows and bottom 60 rows) to make an 640x240 px color image. I want the final format to be `.ppm`.

How can I do this using ImageMagick's `convert` command?

**Edit:** I found I can first reduce the image size to 640x360 px using another tool, and then I can do:

```
convert -crop 640x240 filename.jpg filename_crop.jpg
```

to crop the lower 120 rows to get 640x240 px `.jpg` files. I can use another tool (like web service) to convert them to `.ppm` files at least. But ImageMagick's manual isn't so kind. For example it says:

```
-define format:option
                     define one or more image format options
```

but doesn't say anything about `format:option`.

Comment: For future reference: [XnConvert](https://www.xnview.com/en/xnconvert/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command you need is:

```
convert -resize 640x360\! -crop 640x240+0+60 filename.jpg filename_crop.ppm
```

- The `\!` in the `-resize` command is used to resize the input image (`filename.jpg`) to the specified size without keeping the aspect ratio. If we don't add that, the image will be resized to best fit the given size.
- In the `-crop` command, `640x240` (`width*height`) specify the cropped image's dimensions, while `+0+60` (`+left_offset+top_offset`) specify the offset from the top left of the initial image. In this case, it crops the image with an offset of `60` pixels from the top.